# How can I write summary for a @helper?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I used to have a HtmlHelper written in C# code.  Instead of it, I just created a cool Razor @helper and put it in my App_Code folder!

My HtmlHelper function had a summary:

```
/// <summary>Html Helper for such and such bla..</summary>
/// <param name="param1">The bla bla param</param>
/// <param name="param2">Param2, more bla...</param>
```

so that when a developer is using this Helper, he gets intellisense.  Is there a way to do this for my @helper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that this is probably not possible with the current version of razor.

Thinking about it a bit more would also suggest that it will not be a feature that will be added, as razor is about *less* syntax (terseness) and adding `summary` comments would certainly not help with that goal. The fact that you can have a traditional helper with `summary` means that there is a way to get helpers with summary comments, so not a show stopper for razor either.

I am sure that if this was possible, the gu would have [blogged](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/05/12/asp-net-mvc-3-and-the-helper-syntax-within-razor.aspx) it.

I like the idea though - why not suggest it in a comment to him?

Comment: Hmm... If it's not possible, then suggesting it is a good idea!  I like.

Comment: I think it's unlikely to be added for the reasons Oded gave. This functionality is for very tiny reusable pieces of code within a view, I think the intention is that you could create C# helpers for substantial reusable methods across a project.